# Redmine LDAP authentication fails for SOME users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory, ldap, redmine

I have a redmine instance with configured LDAP authentication. 90-95% of users which are listed in LDAP catalog have no problem with logging into the application(redmine). But some users do, they are present in LDAP, but at the time they try to login into redmine, it responds: Invalid credentials.

My observation is: such issue happens with the users who didnt login into redmine more than 3-5 months. At that time, due to security policy, LDAP system requires the accounts to change their password. So my thought is that when they had changed the password and try to login, there is a conflict between old and new password.

At the same time there is no any problems with LDAP itself (only  when user tries to login into redmine, thats why i thought its some kind of internal application conflict).

```
password_authentication called
try_to_login called
#<User id: 111, login: "qwe", hashed_password: "", firstname: "qwe", lastname: "qwe", admin: false, status: 1, last_login_on: "2020-02-14 04:36:51", language: "", auth_source_id: 1, created_on: "2018-10-05 00:46:00", updated_on: "2019-06-20 01:30:34", type: "User", identity_url: nil, mail_notification: "only_my_events", salt: nil, must_change_passwd: false, passwd_changed_on: nil>
user.nil? = true
user.new_record? =
user.active? =
Failed login for 'qwe' from xxx.xx.xxx.xxx at 2020-03-02 09:29:53 UTC
authenticate_user finished
```

Can you give me some help and advice please? Have no idea what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the issue was that login in Redmine wasnt the same in LDAP catalogues. I went through all login logic, and found that the entity returned required to login was empty due to login mismatch.